# Tabbed pane with several time the same panel

Tags: java, swing

I have three tabs, the first one contain a component, the second one another component, and the third one contains both component from the first and second tab.
On my third tab both components don't appear.  Do I have to make a clone of my first and second component to have it on the third tab?  What if some properties of my components change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, a Swing `JComponent` cannot be added to more than one other `JComponent` (its parent).

If your concern is to share the content of components then you generally have an easy option: since Swing components are based on **MVC**, they all have a **Model** which you can share between several `JComponent`s.

For instance, `JTextComponent` (`JTextField` and `JTextArea` are `JTextComponent`s) has a `Document` as its model, this `Document` can be shared as in the following snippet:

```
JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
JTextField field2 = new JTextField();

field2.setDocument(field1.getDocument());
```

Now if you want to synchronize other properties (e.g. number of columns of `JTextField`), you'll have to use a `PropertyChangeListener` as someone else suggested.

Answer (score 1):

A Swing component can only have one parent at a time. So if you try to add an instance of a component to multiple containers this will not work.

So instead you have to create an instance of the components for every container you would like to add it to.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple tabs cannot have the same component. There is a bug for this in the Sun database:

[Bug: 4176095 - Clarification that no 2 Tabs in JTabbedPane can have same component](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4176095)

There is a proposed fix which has not been incorporated though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this. You can do the following steps
- Add tab listner
- Whenever a tab is selected you can add the components that need to be displayed in the selected tab panel and show it. (i.e., whenever tabpanel is getting displayed we are going reset the components parent details)

Comment: Works perfect for me, simple and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any swing component can be added only to one container.

Answer (score 0):

On each tab you should have separate components, using listeners you can manipulate the properties of those components.

To solve problem like this you should get familiar with MVC design pattern,